# SelectOneRadio not hidden the panelGrid after selection

Tags: primefaces, selectoneradio, panelgrid

I am using primefaces `selectoneradio` control which will show or hide the `panelgrid` after selection. But does not know why it cannot hide this `panelgrid` when selectl allTeachers radio.

```
public boolean getVisibleTeacherList() {
    if (this.selectedAllTeachersFlag == "AllTeachers")
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

---

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{chkTeacherList.selectedAllTeachersFlag}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All teachers" itemValue="AllTeachers" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selected teachers" itemValue="SelectedTeachers" />
        <p:ajax update="panelGrid1a1" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
</p:panelGrid>
<p:panelGrid id="panelGrid1a1" rendered="#{chkTeacherList.getVisibleTeacherList()}" columns="1" styleClass="ui-edb-noneborder-grid">
    <p:separator style="border: 1px solid #8c4eea;" />
    <p:panelGrid id="panelGrid1"  columns="3" styleClass="ui-edb-noneborder-grid">
        <p:selectManyCheckbox layout="grid" id="gridTeacherName"  value="#{chkTeacherList.selectedValue}" 
                             columns="3">
            <f:selectItems value="#{chkTeacherList.filterTeacherNameList}" var="teacher" itemLabel="#{teacher.teacherEngName}" itemValue="#{teacher.timRefNo}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:separator style="border: 1px solid #8c4eea;" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be with your boolean getter `getVisibleTeacherList`. It should be `isVisibleTeacherList` for `visibleTeacherList` property.

More-ever, I think this separate property is not required. You can handle rendering of panelGrid using:

```
rendered="#{chkTeacherList.selectedAllTeachersFlag eq 'AllTeachers'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add or remove component (when it changes its `rendered` value) you need to update not the component itself, but one of its ancestor components.

E.g., say your `panelGrid1a1` is located inside `parentPanel`.

```
<p:outputPanel id="parentPanel">
    <p:panelGrid id="panelGrid1a1" rendered="#{chkTeacherList.getVisibleTeacherList()}" ...
    ...
</p:outputPanel>
```

Then your `p:selectOneRadio`'s `p:ajax` should update `parentPanel`.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="console" ...
    ...
    <p:ajax update="parentPanel" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix try replacing this:

```
this.selectedAllTeachersFlag == "AllTeachers"
```

with

```
this.selectedAllTeachersFlag.equals("AllTeachers")
```

**Difference**

- "==" is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location. where
- "equals()" evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.